# Copy folders and keep their modified date

Tags: rsync, copy-paste, finder

I want to copy a couple of folders and preserve their modified date for historic reasons and not to change the sorting I'm used to.
I have tried using rsync with flags to preserve times and the finders "Paste item exactly".

For files this works fine but it seems macOS or the finder or whatever *still* modifies the "Modified at" date for folders.

Is there a way to copy my folders and keep the modified date?

Edit: Added clarification that I already used rsync with `--times --archive`

Answer (score -1):

man rsync:

```
-t, --times                 preserve modification times
-O, --omit-dir-times        omit directories from --times
-J, --omit-link-times       omit symlinks from --times
```

Comment: This is not enough. Files and dirs are copied as wanted but then something in macOS touches/modifies the folder. A couple of seconds after being copied all the folders modified date is set to now. Not sure if this is Spotlight, Finder or whatever component